# How to add 2 lines in Microchart for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, charts, xamarin.forms

I am now working with the Xamarin Forms and Trying to use the Microchart. I want to show 2 lines in one Linechart so I can compare them. But now I can not put 2 lines in one chart at the same time, is there any solution?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hack. Create two graphs independently and overlay on each other.

In XAML View:

```
<microcharts:ChartView x:Name="chartView1"
    Grid.Row="3"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

<microcharts:ChartView x:Name="chartView2"
    Grid.Row="3"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

In CS File:

List myNumEntries = new List();
List teamNumEntries = new List();

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    myNumEntries.Add(new ChartEntry(new Random().Next(1, 11)){ Color = SKColor.Parse("F09079") });
    teamNumEntries.Add(new ChartEntry(new Random().Next(1, 11)){ Color = SKColor.Parse("3569B1") });
}

chartView1.Chart = new LineChart { Entries = myNumEntries, BackgroundColor = SKColor.Empty };
chartView2.Chart = new LineChart { Entries = teamNumEntries, BackgroundColor = SKColor.Empty };
```